# How to concatenate trained dataset and untrain dataset Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I input train_generator for train then concatenate another dataset, every image have correspond concate image.

But when shuffle = True , I dont know how to concatenate correspond concate image.

For example, train_generator have A B C and I want to concatenate A & A_temp, B & B_temp, C & C_temp then GAP2D, softmax.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory()
train_Temp_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_Temp_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory()

conv_base = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(weights=None,include_top=False , input_shape=(299,299,3))
conv_base.trainable = True
for layers in conv_base.layers[:-20]:
    conv_base.trainable = False
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(conv_base, train_Temp_generator))   #Concatenate
model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(7,activation='softmax')) 
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_generator)
```

Or I shouldn't use "train_Temp_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()" , just concatenate conv_base & Temp_folder with same filename?

Comment: Kindly concatenate corresponding images from train_generator and train_Temp_generator and then train your model.
You need to use concatenate function from the tf.keras.layers module to merge the features from both generators.
Use below code to concatenate datasets.            
# Concatenate the output of conv_base with the input_temp
   `concatenated = Concatenate()([model.output, input_temp])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[model.input, input_temp], outputs=concatenated)`